# UE4 Error lighting needs to be rebuilt

Tags: lighting, unreal-4

I opened a blank project that came with two types of flooring, a table with two chairs and a statue.

The only things I modified was the size of one of the floors and the texture of the two floors.

When I did this, the following message appeared: **LIGHTING NEEDS TO BE REBUILT (2 unbuilt objects)**

**I clicked on the option below (Compile Only Lighting):**

[image]

**Compilation failed (view image below), the following error appeared (0xc000007b):**

[image]

Note that the Swarm Agent is working.

I restarted the program several times. I cleared the cache. I fixed the program. I started a new project. All this did not result in anything.

**Below are some links that I researched and tried to solve the problem, doing almost everything I was told:**

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/201327/lightning-build-failed-swarm-failed-to-kick-off.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/12975/unreal-engine-wont-launch-error-code-0xc000007b.html

Comment: The error code refers to a 64 bit program trying to load a 32 bit dll.  One of the solutions I found was with the file D3DX9_43.dll in DirectX.  Have you tried reinstalling this?

Comment: I downloaded both the 32-bit and 64-bit ones and I replaced them in the system32 and SysWOW64 folders respectively. I rebooted the computer. The problem persists.

Comment: I had already visited this page, but I let this attempt pass. https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/12975/unreal-engine-wont-launch-error-code-0xc000007b.html

Comment: I have another project, but already created as an FPS (native to the program) in it I made several modifications (I changed textures, added objects) and even then the warning does not appear to rebuild the lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not remember exactly what modification I did on my computer, but when I tried to open the UE4 the following error appeared:**

[image]

*(image taken from the internet)*

It is not the first time that this error occurs, but there I went to solve it again (If I remember correctly I deleted the folder with the libraries (.dll) that resolved it the first time, so I had to download it again):

But before, a poetic pause... One day Albert Einstein said: ***Insanity is to keep doing the same thing and expect different results***.

So this time I looked for another place to try to solve this error, :

(**VIDEO LINK**) => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA4N0x4iG54

In this video the man orders to download a compressed file that contains three folders.

(**COMPRESSED FILE**) => http://www.mediafire.com/file/at50mz3rkobxe4i/Erro+0xc000007b.rar

You should copy all libraries from the first folder and paste them into the sytem32 folder (if your system is 32-bit) and the system32 and SysWOW64 folders (if your system is 64-bit).

**Your pasting must be of the type that replaces existing files:**

[image]

**You will need to give administrator permission for the computer to do this:**

[image]

**There will be an "error", you select the "do this for all current items" box and then click ignore:**

[image]

**Once you click Ignore you will notice that there are numerous selected files. Press the delete key and enter to delete them (again you will have to provide administrator permission):**

[image]

NOTE => **For users of a 64-bit computer, you will have to do this in both folders (system32 and SysWOW64).**

In the second folder of the file that the video man made available has the directX installer. **I RECOMMEND NOT TO USE, BECAUSE WITH ME IT DID NOT WORK.** I even had to reinstall directX.

(**OFICIAL LINK OF DIRECTX**) => https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/179113/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx

**Just install DirectX.**

In the third folder of the file that the video man provided, there is another installer (all versions of Visual Studio) that also did not work for me.

(**OFICIAL LINK 64-bit**) => https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36805

*Sorry, I downloaded 32-bit too, but I can not find the link.*

**Just install all versions of Visual Studio from Microsoft.**

That way I killed two birds with one stone.

**The lighting build works and the error has been fixed.**

Comment: I removed a dead link from your answer. If you can, please update it and redirect visitors to "official" sites (e.g. directly to microsoft.com) as links to those generally rot less. Thanks!